# Angular JS get object by id from $routeparams

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to retrieve an object by ID from the server using the $routeparams.

My problem is the $routeparams only has access to the "slug" of the item. Here is my current code.

Controller:

```
dataService.getVolunteerByID($routeParams.id)
.then(getVolunteerSuccess)
  .catch(errorCallback);  


function getVolunteerSuccess(data) {
    $scope.volunteer = data;
  }
```

Service:

```
  function getVolunteerByID(volunteerID) {
    return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/vol/' + volunteerID
  })
  .then(sendResponseData)
  .catch(sendGetVolunteerError);
}
```

The current code is just appending the slug field instead of the id.

Comment: if you are using a query in the url, ` ?id=123` and you use html5 mode, you can retrieve query parameters with $location.search().id

Comment: if instead you are using parameters and your current route is `/current-route/:itemId`  then in the controller  you can retrieve the parameter with $routeParams.itemId

Comment: I'd like to pass in the slug name for a clean url and one that people can access directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with a forEach loop and passing the $routeparam on the response.config object. I think this is the best approach?

```
function getVolunteerByID(shortname) {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/vol',
    shortname: shortname
})
  .then(getVolunteerByIDSuccess)
  .catch(sendGetVolunteerError);
}



function getVolunteerByIDSuccess(response) {
    var log = [];  
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(item, key) {
          if(item.shortname == response.config.shortname){
            console.log(item);
            this.push(item);
        }
    }, log);
    return log;
  }
```